# Vim8/NeoVim Invalid Expression remapping <C-x><C-o> to <Tab> for OmniShap-vim

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I was reading a blog post for [Settings up a C# Development Environment with Vim on Debian](https://medium.com/@kpereksta/setting-up-a-c-development-environment-with-vim-on-debian-ea42d5b810) and I got most of this going except I have an issue with the `<C-x><C-o>` inoremap'ing. I am running both Vim 8.2 and NeoVim 0.4.3 on WSL on Windows 10. [OmniSharp-Vim](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim) seems to have installed and started OmniSharp-roslyn as when I do `ps aux` I see the `/home/user01/.cache/omnisharp-vim/omnisharp-roslyn/bin/mono /home/user01/.cache/omnisharp-vim/omnisharp-roslyn/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe` command running.

The original line is:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' :                                                                                                                    
\ getline('.')[col('.')-2] =~# '[[:alnum:].-_#$]' ? '<C-x><C-o>' : '<Tab>'
```

and I thought to wrap it in an `augroup` with an `autocmd` so its not always running.

```
augroup phil_omnisharp_settings
  autocmd FileType cs inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' : \ getline('.')[col('.')-2] =~# '[[:alnum:].-_#$]' ? '<C-x><C-o>' : '<Tab>'

  "autocmd FileType cs remap <C-o><C-u> :OmniSharpFindUsages<CR>
  autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <C-o><C-d> :OmniSharpGotoDefinition<CR>
  autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <C-o><C-d><C-p> :OmniSharpPreviewDefinition<CR>
  autocmd FileType cs nnoremap <C-o><C-r> :!dotnet run
augroup END
```

This will start as expected, but when I get to a `System.Console.<Tab>` I get the following error:

```
E15: Invalid expression: \ getline('.')[col('.')-2] =~# '[[:alnum:].-_#$]' ? '^X^O' : '^I'
```

or `System.Console.<C-x><C-o>` sequence I get the following error:

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

I would just run Vim/NeoVim on Windows, but I ran into issues with neither having `+python` or `+python3` support enabled. Vim 8.2 had something called `+python/dyn` enabled, which OmniSharp didn't seem to like either if I used the HTTP method, and the socket method didn't work either.

GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/01525f9d82b71972f16882de789e6569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate key sequences as strings, you need to use double-quoted strings and quote the `<` with a backslash. Such as `"\<C-x>\<C-o>"`.

See [`:help expr-quote`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) for more details (single quote strings are under `:help literal-string`).

Putting it all together:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
\ getline('.')[col('.')-2] =~# '[[:alnum:].-_#$]' ? "\<C-x>\<C-o>" : "\<Tab>"
```

Comment: I am still getting the `^O^N^P` error when I manually type in `<C-x><C-o>` and when I press tab in INSERT mode, I get the following still. `E15: Invalid expression: \ getline('.')[col('.')-2] =~# '[[:alnum:].-_#$]' ? "\^X\^O" : "\^I"`. I copied the line you used because I thought I had an error when I typed it in.

Comment: @Pred Looks like you typed the literal characters, escaping them with CTRL-V. Type the `\<C-X>` as 6 separate characters, backslash, `<`, uppercase C, dash, X, `>`.

Comment: I typed the whole thing in by hand this time, but I am still getting the same error. I'll include a GitHub Gist of the `vimrc` snippet and error. https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/01525f9d82b71972f16882de789e6569

Comment: @Pred It seems the problem is with the \, that's used as a line continuation when you break lines short, so you start the second line with a \. If you're not breaking the line, just omit the \.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense. The \ character is when a statement is split over multiple lines. I removed that. So, this all seems to only work in WSL with Vim/NeoVim rather than the Windows version of Vim and NeoVim. When I press <Tab> in the WIndows version, it just inserts a `\t` character. In WSL, the menus actually pop up. I also think the Windows version is using the .NET Framework rather than the .NET Core installation to do its linting.

Comment: @Pred Not sure what to say about the Windows non-WSL issue... If you can create a minimal reproducer for that and you can reproduce that under `vim -u NONE -N` or `vim --clean` etc., then I suggest you open a separate question about that issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

In an `<expr>` mapping there is actually nothing wrong with using single quotes. An `<expr>` mapping expects a string which it interprets as the mapping RHS when it is invoked. So the original mapping is perfectly correct.

Your error comes in because the original mapping is split over 2 lines, which requires a line continuation character `\`. When you have joined it into a single line, you must remove the backslash. So to use that line in an autocmd, it should become:

```
" Original version, for comparison:
" autocmd FileType cs inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' : \ getline('.')[col('.')-2] =~# '[[:alnum:].-_#$]' ? '<C-x><C-o>' : '<Tab>'
"                                                        remove this ^
  autocmd FileType cs inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' : getline('.')[col('.')-2] =~# '[[:alnum:].-_#$]' ? '<C-x><C-o>' : '<Tab>'
```

*Edit:* I see you eventually worked that out in the comments, but I'll still post this answer to make it clear what the actual fix for your error was.